# Using accuracy function with sarima input argument to get in-sample-accuracy measures

Tags: r, time-series, verification

I have fitted a Box-Jenkins model, ARIMA(2,1,0) to an univariate time series (length=38) and would like to get some in-sample accuracy measures (e.g. ME, RMSE,  MAE, MAPE etc.) on the model fit in order to compare the Box-Jenkins model to an exponential smoothing model (model verification). Now, I try to use the accuracy function from the "forecast package" which takes an object of class "forecast" as input argument. It is stated that it will also work with Arima
(http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/accuracy). I do not seem to get it working though. My code:

```
x <- sarima(mytimeseries, 2,1,0)$fit

accuracy(x)
```

I get the following error:

> Warning message: In trainingaccuracy(f, test, d, D) : test elements
>   must be within sample

I do not quite understand what the warning message actually says. The basic setting the argument 'test' is NULL so that all elements are tested. How do I get the in-sample-accuracy measures (model verification) from the function accuracy in the forecast package?

Answer (score 0):

The `accuracy` function is expecting an object of class `forecast`, but in your case `class(x) == "Arima"`. You will first need to pass `mytimeseries` to `sarima.for` (or `predict`), and then pass that object to `accuracy`.

Comment: I have passed mytimeseries to sarima.for which, surprisingly, does not give an object of class forecast but a list. Coercing the list to an object of class time series (which the 'accuracy' function should accept according to the function description) does not work either: i ge the same error as in my first message saying the test elements must be within sample

On a side note: I have also passed mytimeseries to 'predict' but this also returns an object of class list.